# Add a record to Access with text from a text box

Tags: ms-access

In MS-Access, I have a form with textboxs and a button, and I want it so that when I click on the button, it will add the data  in the textboxs to a new record.
How do I do this?

> Note: I do not have much experience in Access

Comment: Can you expand on your question regarding what the form will be used for, any details that might help us provide a good answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this using an unbound form.

Assume your destination table is named **Table1** and has the following format:

```
Field Name        Data Type
-------------     ---------------
ID                AutoNumber
Field1            Text
Field2            Text
```

Assume your form is named **Form1** and has the following controls:

```
Control Name      Control Type
-------------     ---------------
Text0             Text Box
Text2             Text Box
Command4          Command Button
```

Finally the **On Click** event of the *Command4* control is assigned the following *Event Procedure*:

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()

  Dim rs As Recordset

  On Error GoTo ErrHandler

  If MsgBox("Do you want to add the record.", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Add New Record?") = vbYes Then

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table1", dbOpenDynaset)
    rs.AddNew
      rs.Fields("Field1").Value = Me.Text0.Value
      rs.Fields("Field2").Value = Me.Text2.Value
    rs.Update

    MsgBox "Record saved.", vbInformation, "Record Saved"

  End If

  Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error Occurred"

End Sub
```

This code will first prompt the user to confirm that the record should be saved. If the answer is yes the record will be inserted into the table and a confirmation message will be displayed. If an error occurs, the code will jump to the ErrHandler section and display a message box with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do it.

Firstly you can make the form a bound form, so that the form is bound to a table (form RecordSource), and you bound the texboxt to a field in table.

Secondly you can write some VBA code that will insert the record into the table, using an INSERT INTO sql statement